# PCF Scheduling jobs

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have been trying to schedule spring cloud task via PCF scheduler, however I can't create a job from the app/task (following this documentation on the site - http://docs.pivotal.io/pcf-scheduler/1-1/using-jobs.html)

1. > $ cf apps 
   >   name                                requested state   instances   memory   disk   urls 
   >   **cloud-task                          stopped           0/1         750M     1G**
2. > $ cf services 
   >   name                   service                       plan        bound apps
   >     last operation 
   >   **my-scheduler           scheduler-for-pcf             standard    cloud-task
   >     create succeeded**
3. > $ cf create-job cloud-task my-task-job ".java-buildpa
   >   ck/open_jdk_jre/bin/java org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"

Creating job ←[33;1mmy-task-job←[0m for ←[33;1mcloud-task←[0m with command ←[33;1m.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/java org.springframework.boot.loade
r.JarLauncher←[0m in org ←[33;1mglobal-sales-marketing-customer-experience←[0m / space ←[33;1m141349-dev←[0m as ←[33;1mzzh1bb←[0m
←[31;1mFAILED←[0m
The requested resource was not found.
  Not Found
  You must create an instance of the scheduler service in this space to use the scheduler service.

**Not sure why the job creation command is not able to find the instance of scheduler service - Am I missing something here ?**

*Also, wondering if there is anything in spring-clould-data-flow that can schedule tasks.*

Answer (score 1):

From the output you should be able to create a job in that org/space.

Does the user (zzh1bb?) have SpaceDeveloper privileges?  SpaceAdmin should also be sufficient.

Does a cf task execute successfully using:

```
cf run-task cloud-task ".java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/java org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"
```

And seeing results with:

```
cf tasks cloud-task
```

Another diagnostic step might be to check the output of the api calls described here: 
  http://docs.pivotal.io/pcf-scheduler/1-1/api/#create-job

What version of PCF are you using and what version of the Scheduler for PCF are you using?  There were significant changes in the cloud controller api between 1.10, 1.11 and 1.12 that prevent the scheduler service from working across all of those versions.

As far as scheduling SCDF, the Scheduler for PCF service can be used in conjunction with SCDF to allow you to call the task execution endpoint from a Schedeler for PCF call (https://docs.pivotal.io/pcf-scheduler/1-1/using-calls.html).

Call SCDF using the execution endpoint

```
http://...scdf server.../tasks/executions?name=taskA
```

doc'ed here:

```
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_launching_a_task_2
```

This is very useful and convenient especially when creating the SCDF service and the Scheduler for PCF service in the same space.